# No output from Sapphire Radeon R9 270X

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I've got a gaming rig I built. It's been running well for a long time, but recently I've run into some trouble with it

Here's the set up

- [Sapphire Radeon R9 270X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FLMKN6I)
- [EVGA supernova 750 g2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817438017)
- [Corsair Vengeance Pro DDR3 2400MHz PC3 19200 2x8gb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EUPV2RQ)
- [ASUS M5A97 R2.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008V9959O)
- [AMD FX-8350 Black Edition Vishera](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819113284)
- An SSD
- A spinning disk

Here are the symptoms I've noticed

- Initially, the rig worked great! After some time (~1 year), I noticed spurious restarts. They were few and far between so I didn't worry. Eventually, it wouldn't boot up.  I noticed a funny smell coming from my power supply. I worked with EVGA customer support to replace it and everything was good again
- Six months later the reboots returned. The power supply seems fine.
- The reboots worsened to the point the computer was unusable
- The reboots stopped. The computer would turn on, but the screens would remain black. At this point, holding down the power button no longer reset the computer
- I tried tightening all connections and making sure no wires were loose. I re-seated the graphics card, tried it in the second slot, and returned it to the first slot
- The computer booted up. At boot, I got a message that overclock had failed and I need to go into the bios to fix it. I set power consumption to normal and rebooted.
- Windows repair came up. I chose the "restart" option
- The computer booted normally, then crashed again. It returned to the "black screen" state
- After some time in the "black screen" state it loaded windows. This process repeated itself a few times

I'm at a loss for what to do, and would very much appreciate any tips or debugging steps. When it happens again, what should I do? Thank you!

EDIT: after running for ~15 minutes, I was able to update my graphics card driver. I started the process of updating the bios, but as I plugged in an external drive to save the *.cap image to, the screen went blank

EDIT 2: I got a new [graphics card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MEFABEL), but still no luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fought 3 months this sort of issue with my old AMD 6970HD 2Gb - eventually it died. Your problem sounds exactly the same - especially when you have overclocked the GPU.

I suggest getting another GPU for testing purposes, if everythings ok with it, time to go shopping for new card. Free tip - do not overclock, it can cost you quite amount of bucks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I got a new graphics card (one of [these](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MEFABEL/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) , but still no luck. Do you have any other suggestions?